# Starting the console with my own graph

Tags: neo4j

To experiment with Cypher I wanted to load the console with my own graph. Two questions here come:

1. Can I do it on a locally installed server?
2. How to provide the graph configuration (the "graph setup" piece) as a default setup?

Thanks!

Comment: there is also the option of passing in url=http://host:port/db/data/cypher to the console which pulls in the graph of that publicly accessible server

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can run console yourself against your own database. This assumes you have git, maven and jdk properly installed.

1. `git clone git://github.com/neo4j-contrib/rabbithole.git`
2. `cd rabbithole`
3. `mvn assembly:single`
4. `java -cp "target/neo4j-console-jar-with-dependencies.jar" org.neo4j.community.console.Console <port> <path-to-local-db> expose`

If you add expose to the end of the last command above, it will make it so the database is actually writable. Leave it off if you want a read-only copy. Note that you can't run rabbithole with expose at the same time that you're running neo4j server, as they both try to lock the files.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean with the console, but if you mean http://console.neo4j.org:

1. Yes. Download the source code from https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/rabbithole
2. Clicking the <kbd>share</kbd> button opens up a dialog where you can edit the graph create statement, and the initial query.  When you are done, click the <kbd>click to generate</kbd> button, and an URL will be generated in the input below.  Just bookmark this URL, to retrieve it later.