# is there a nice cypher desktop client for neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying out a lot of cypher queries on my neo4j database and have found the web based console to be a bit clumsy.

The neo4j console is more useful ,but I am not sure how to point it at my own database/dataset.

Is there a nice desktop client or tool to run cypher queries on as well as manage a neo4j database, akin to the SQL management studio?

I'd like to avoid using the web admin if possible.

Comment: The best place is console.neo4j.org

Comment: but I can't point the neo4j console to my own db..

Comment: Actually, you can run console against your own db. But you run into problems actually using it with a big dataset, because it wants to render the whole graph.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270730/starting-the-console-with-my-own-graph/14349585#14349585 for instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start a neo4j server it also spins up a wed-based admin tool that allows you to submit adhoc queries via a tool and see the results. Just go to your server's URL in your web browser.

There is also a decent visualization tool called [Neoclipse](https://github.com/neo4j/neoclipse). It's got some small bugs and a bit of a learning curve but it's pretty decent.

Comment: I found the webadmin to be a bit cludgy in terms of output and editing queries.

Comment: It seems to hang on first connect to the datbase as it looks like it's trying to pull down everything (all nodes).  How can I prevent that?

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey I couldn't say, I haven't used neoclipse with any database over a couple thousand nodes.